# Rotation in 3D automatically using CSS

Tags: css

I want to rotate a picture as 3D using CSS. I want to rotate with axis Y. I have tried but it doesn't work. I have picture that is like cylinder. So, that picture middle point should be in origin. And it should rotate with Y axis.

```
<style>
#picture{
            position: absolute;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;              
            padding-top:300px;
            padding-left: 450px;
            text-align:center;
              overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
                -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
                -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
                 -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
                  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;


        }
        @keyframes picture {
         from {
           -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
             -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
             -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
             transform: rotate(0deg);
         }
         to {
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
           -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
             }
          }


</style>

<div id="container">
 <img id="picture" src="textures/toothpaste.png">
</div>
```

I have tried this. But it doesn't work.

Comment: and what if you add full url of the image, don't you think we cannot see it like that :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)